# Передача изображения с экрана, с андроид приложения на экран SmartTV

Tags: android

Есть телефон на андроид. Написал приложение. На нем запускается приложение. Необходимо что бы все что отображается на экране, отображалось и на ТВ экране. Собственном вопрос как это можно сделать.

Пытался нагуглить информацию о том как такое делается, но возможно я не до конца все понимал, и так и не нашел как такое реализовать.

Собственно вопрос, возможно ли в принципе такое сделать, и если да, то в какую сторону копать ? Есть ли у кого то опыт в этом ?

Спасибо.

Comment: использовать телевизор через micro hdmi телефона, если такой есть? У меня такая система работает уже 2 года. По факту - со старого планшета и телевизора - smartTv

Comment: То есть на телефоне и на ТВ должен быть разъем micro hdmi ? Или на телефоне подключается USB с переходником на micro hdmi который подключается к ТВ ?

Comment: на ТВ - hdmi, на телефоне - micro hdmi. Конект - через переходники или специальный кабель

Comment: А если на телефоне hdmi разъема нету ?

Comment: как минимум - указать модель телефона (в некоторых есть возможность подключать внешний монитор через micro usb), хотя апаратно не все такое могут сделать

Comment: На данный момент не известна модель апарата на которой прийдется работать, известы ли вам варианты сделать это в случае если у апарата не будет разъема hdmi ?

Comment: разве что на ТВ будет какая-то операционка и возможностью конекта по WiFi. Иначе - будет очень длинный велосипед и костыль в одном лице

Comment: Это будет SmartTv, а на них насколько мне известна стоит операционка, возможно даже тоже андроид будет стоять. Вот тут я и забуксовал, нет ли у вас информации как в данном случае по тому же Wi-Fi подключить апарат к ТВ ?

Comment: по факту - это будет управление ТВ через смартфон, или управляющим устройством выступает телефон а ТВ - будет простым екраном?

Comment: ТВ будет простым экраном, он должен просто дублировать то что показывается на телефоне.

Answer (score 1):

Если это телефон с Android 4.4 и выше, а телевизор Android TV или есть Chromecast, то с помощью Remote Display можно показывать на ТВ что угодно.
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote

А если это телефон с Android 5.0 и выше, то он сам умеет зеркалить экран на Android TV или Chromecast.